# symfony2 security.yml working only in dev environment

Tags: security, symfony, environment

Working on my first symfony project I was following the tutorial about the security mechanisms. I started using the "http_basic" mode in my firewall. The strange thing is that it works only in dev mode and not in prod. This is my `security.yml`:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    test: {password: test, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER'] }
                    admintest: { password: admintest, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:

        prod:
            pattern: ^/
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured B2B Area"
            security: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/B2B, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I created the project with NetBeans.

What I see is that if I use the path: `app_dev.php/B2B` I can see the login/pwd interface and everything works fine, but if I use the path `app.php`, I can directly access my site without any authorization request.
After any `security.yml` changes, I cleared the cache with the command: `php console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I have the same strange problem. even stranger since the behaviour in three envs is different in each one of them. 
Did you solve it yet by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

DEV and PROD environment use the same session context. So you must log out (from any environment) to see the login form.

Comment: can you please expalin me better? Even if I access app.php as first (first browser run) the result is the same, no login at all. What do you mean exactly with log out? Thanks in advance

Comment: When you log in DEV environment, you're logged in PROD environment too. The session (used to identify user) is not restricted to environment.